# Menu from menu button disappeared?

Tags: menu

I would like to know why the menu button has been removed from Android in Android 6 and 7 mobile phones, hosting an apps button instead. Thanks.

(I remember long pressing the home button on Android 4 to get to the apps list.)

Comment: Because for the majority of modern apps, the 3-dot menu is now visible in the apps themselves (on the action bar)? Menu key is a legacy design.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the recents panel rests there for easier multitasking. That's the aim of any computer developer since that makes it more productive